# ARMv8A AArch64 vmlal_high_s8 Intrinsics

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

I'm looking for the intrinsic corresponding to the operation 'SMLAL2 Vd.8H,Vn.16B,Vm.16B', which according to ARM's own documentation ([ARM Neon Intrinsics Ref](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0073a/IHI0073A_arm_neon_intrinsics_ref.pdf)) should be something like

```
int16x8_t vmlal_high_s8 (int16x8_t a,int8x16_t b,int8x16_t c)
```

however in the arm_neon.h that is included in [ARM's GNU Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) doesn't have anything corresponding to it. So my question would be if I have to just include something else or otherwise can somehow circumvent this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried vmlal_s8(vget_high(a), vget_high(b), vget_high(c))  ?

Comment: @BitBank Thanks for the quick reply. I guess that would then only get half of the job done as I would take only the high parts of the registers? That should work I guess but I would need two instructions to achieve the same thing that way...

Comment: Try it and see what the compiler generates. If it does a good job, it will use the '2' version of the instruction.

Comment: Found the culprit: wrong toolchain, thanks anyway @BitBank

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else hitting this problem: I had chosen the ARM embedded tool chain instead of the linaro one, which is suitable for aarch64